# Ionic2 round segment-button

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

does anyone know how to change the css of a segment- button from square to round ?

[image]

I tried using normal [css](http://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/) but it gets wierd when ionic2 tries to transform the button on `segment-activated` Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q58A1UFuThCqNG75JbXd?p=preview) example

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="date" danger>
  <ion-segment-button value="1">
    1
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="2">
    2
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button value="3">
    3
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

With normal css I failed. and it gets weird when you select another button
[image]

Comment: Could you put what you've tried into a plunker? this will give people something to play about with http://plnkr.co/edit/me3Uk0GKWVRhZWU0usad?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for that @Will.Harris

Comment: have you tried to override Sass variables? See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/overriding-ionic-variables/, part $segment-*

Comment: @hhhung yes I tried. there is no sass to round the button. it only has sass to round the edges

Comment: sorry, there is no way to round buttons like that with sass variables. I don't think you should implement segment such way, because it's style is not intend for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a hack to do it. **NB** this is a hack and the style is not intend for this.

Css solution: place this in your `.scss` file

```
ion-segment-button{
  //max-width: 25px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.segment-button {
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #e62100;
  color: #e62100;
  border-width: thin;
}

.segment-button:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
  // margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  line-height: 3.4rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%}
.segment-button:not(:first-of-type) {
  border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
 // margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 3.4rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;}
.segment-button:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 90px 90px 90px 90px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  line-height: 3.4rem;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;}


 .segment-activated{
  background-color: #e62100;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: worked after wrapping page scss content into .ios, .md { page {<<css classes>> }}