# How to build a round segment in Angular/Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a round segment using `<ion-segment>` and `<ion-segment-button>` components.
I found the same question here on Stack but it wasn't so useful and I didn't find a way to achieve it.

This is what I tried with segment component:

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g1']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g2']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g3']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g4']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g5']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g6']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>

   <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
     <ion-segment (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           <ion-label>{{date['d1']}}</ion-label>
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           {{date['d2']}}
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           {{date['d3']}}
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           {{date['d4']}}
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           {{date['d5']}}
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
       <ion-col size="2">
         <ion-segment-button>
           {{date['d6']}}
         </ion-segment-button>
       </ion-col>
     </ion-segment>
   </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>
```

And this is the result I got:

[image: screen1]

Apart from the alignment (due to the width of segment button, that exceeds the column) I've understand that probably these components don't allow me to do it, 
so I tried to build the same using buttons:

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g1']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g2']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g3']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g4']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g5']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="date_label" size="2">
       <ion-label>{{date['g6']}}</ion-label>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>

   <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d1']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d2']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d3']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d4']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d5']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
     <ion-col class="ion-no-padding" size="2">
       <ion-button color="light" class="ion-no-padding">
         {{date['d6']}}
       </ion-button>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
 </ion-grid>`
```

[image: screen2]

Graphically it's what I'm looking for, but since these are buttons, I don't know how to implement the selector behaviour (when one button is pushed, change its CSS to make it selected, when another button is pushed, remove the CSS and add it to the pressed button)

Just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38527700/ionic2-round-segment-button) question, this is the final result I'd like to build.
[image: screen3]

Answer (score 0):

Making circles is about CSS, a border radius of half the with and height makes a circle. You can use an after to make a circle that floats with the element. Just pick an element in the ionic DOM an target it with classes like this.

```css
.selected {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marked {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.marked::after {
  content: ' ';
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius:3px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  left: -10px;
  top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="selected">10</div>

<div class="marked">10</div>
```

If you post what the rendered DOM of the Ionic output is I can help you apply it there. Or even better make a working StackBlitz from the Ionic template https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic and I can add the CSS there for you.

Comment: I created a new StackBlitz but I'm having problems with button's text width, it appreas only partially...however this is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qkgmbn

Comment: Also, since the columns dimensions change according to the screen, increasing the display size of different devices, the circle becomes oval